# How to get peak power of sound in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After record a sound in Unity, is it possible to get the peak power of the sound? Or is it have any way to calculate the peak power of a sound?

Comment: I think you could find this Game Development answer interesting: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14642/how-do-audio-based-games-such-as-audiosurf-and-beat-hazard-work

Answer (score 3):

Peak isn't very interesting in sound. If you want something closer to perceived volume of the sound, one pretty good metric is RMS. To get this, you have to do just a bit of math:

- Load the sample data using `audio.GetOutputData`
- Sum squares of all the sampled values
- Take the square root of `sum / amountOfSamples` - that's RMS (root-mean-square)
- If you want to have a value in dB, you can get it as `20 * log10(rms / reference)`, where `reference` stands for the value you want to have at `0 dB`. A good reference point is `0.1`, for example. Note that the RMS value will always be from `0` to `1`, while dB values are a bit wilder - they better approximate human hearing, though. If you want to be really serious, different frequencies are perceived at different volumes - have a look at dBA, for example.

Comment: hi Luaan, thanks for ur reply, actually I want to use the peak power to detect blowing. I have found some ios example which is using peak power to do calculation and detect blowing.

Comment: @ZynGie Well, if you really want *peak*, just get the highest number from the samples. The tricky part is that this is not quite how sound works (wave interference makes you lose a lot of the original information), so you might still be better off using RMS or similar - but yeah, in a silent room with little reverbation and such, peak might work as well.